# Symfony 4 EasyAdmin - Property does not render when overriding bundle template

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony2-easyadmin

Using Symfony 4.1 with EasyAdmin bundle.

I am trying to override a template for the User (one of my entites) show view. I have set up the override and it is working.

1. Created a user_show.html.twig and registered it in the easy_admin config file.
2. I then copy the twig blocks from corresponding bundle template for show.html.twig.
3. Then tried to render a User property from my user entity, called profile height.

Here are twig blocks I'm overriding:

```
{# templates/admin/user_show.html.twig #}
{% extends '@EasyAdmin/default/show.html.twig' %}

{% block content_title %}
    Test Title {{ dump() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    {{ profileHeight }}
{% endblock %}
```

**Error**

```
Twig_Error_Runtime: Variable "profileHeight" does not exist
```

**Debug**

I did a dump and found the property is present on page:

[image]

Why can twig not see these variables appearing in the dump? How can I render the properties I want in the template?

Comment: It should be `entity.profileHeight`

Comment: yes I tried {{ user.profileHeight }} and error updates to Variable "user" does not exist.

Comment: @TimothyAURA Because it should be literally `entity.profileHeight`

Comment: Ok that worked. What if I had two entities with property name. Would I use entity,name and entity.related_entity.name. Also someone answer question so I can mark correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in your dumped data, there is `entity` array key which hold the `User` object. So instead of:

```
{% block main %}
  {{ profileHeight }}
{% endblock %}
```

Use:

```
{% block main %}
  {{ entity.profileHeight }}
{% endblock %}
```